# How can I keep brownies from sticking to the pan?

Tags: baking

Whenever I bake brownies they stick to the pan. Is it because I don't use a  non-stick pan, or is this related to the thickness of batter? Maybe there is some other reason.

Answer (score 2):

A non-stick pan will help.  You could also use butter or oil to grease the pan, but most convenient would be a cooking spray.

Comment: And, for what it is worth, we always use parchment paper, works a treat! And the brownies lift right out.